# How do make a get request with Multiple params in angular

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to do an insert statement and it have two params userid and store. But it doesn't seem to be working

```
addToFavorites(Store,User){
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8888/PeopleService/GetStore&Offers/Favorite.php?STORE='+ Store +'&User='+User)
    .do(this.logResponse)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.catchError); 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? any errors? what is the response? please read [mcve]

Comment: sorry I forgot to add error  "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Query"" and "TypeError: error.json is not a function. (In 'error.json()', 'error.json' is undefined)"

Comment: Just [edit] the post and include the details please

Comment: I don't think this will be necessary I found a solution the problem was with the .map but thank for your help I don't notice my mistake if you didn't ask about the error -_-

Answer (score 0):

Use **URLSearchParams** from @angular/http

```
addToFavorites(Store,User) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('STORE', Store);
    params.append('User', User);
    return this.http.get(
        'http://localhost:8888/PeopleService/GetStore&Offers/Favorite.php, 
        { search : params}
    )
    .map(v => this.extractData(v))
    .catch(err => this.catchError(err));
}
```